# Why is writing "alot" such a common mistake?

Tags: orthography

Why is it such a common mistake (particularly among school-children) to connect certain pairs of separate words? The most obvious example probably being:

> e.g. "a lot"->"alot"

Is it because- in this particular case at least- there is already a valid word "allot" that exists?

Maybe also, it helps that "a" is a valid prefix to a word (e.g. "a-plenty").

Comment: Because the space bar of the keyboard is so small it's easy to miss?

Comment: I voted to close because I think this question is just rhetorical; the OP already knows the answer, and wants agreement.

Comment: *although*, *already*, *almost*, *alright*... as you said in the question, it is probably because of confusion with other words. I can't think of any way to truly answer this any more definitively than your speculation.

Comment: The real question here seems to be "Why do people make mistakes with language?" This is a question of the focus and quality of education. Similarly, Why do children say "your" when they mean "you're", as in "your great!"?  The answer is they don't much care to be correct, or haven't been taught the difference.

Comment: I WISH it were just children, instead of my co-workers, friends, and other adults.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly people have a natural tendency to spell "alot" in a single word because the brain processes it as a single word. At any rate, with its use for quantification, it clearly has some "special" properties. Notice the difference in verb agreement between:

> *A lot of* the problems *are* due to bad planning.
>
> *A lot from* the auctions *is* missing.

This taken with the fact that "a lot" can be used adverbially ("he got a lot further") probably make it "feel" like a single item in terms of how the brain processes it. The perceived "obligation" to spell it as two words, like any spelling, is just an arbitrary convention.

A five-year-old child learning to write may not have even come across the word "lot" outside the phrase "a lot of", and occasional phrases such as "a whole lot of" which split "a" and "lot" are rare compared to the basic phrase.

Comment: +1 I wonder if kids subconsciously peg *“alotta”* as a determiner. It kinda makes sense.

Comment: Maybe it's not even really a mistake?

Answer (score 5):

As usual, there’s a certain logic to this common mistake.

Of course if you have read and learned the spelling, it makes sense the way you’ve learned it. But imagine for a second that you weren’t really the reading type, and you didn’t know how *a lot* was spelled. Would you think of it as two words?

Consider *We care a lot*. Is *lot* a noun there? How many other nouns can do that? *We care a bicycle*? *We care a friendship*? I could accept *We care a bunch / a bit / a little*, and a few temporal expressions like *We care this year / all the time*, but a million other nouns don’t work. So it’s no wonder some people put *a lot* in the same mental bucket as *sometimes*, *occasionally*, and *deeply*.

Also— *a lot* is an idiom. It does not mean the same thing in the everyday *We have a lot* as it does in the more literal *We have a lot in the Appalachians where we’re going to build a cabin someday*. There is a pattern in English that such idioms tend to get fused into single words: *all ready/already*, *all most/almost*, *a wake/awake*, *a way/away*, and *a live/alive*. This also explains why *alright* is so common.

Of course the standard spelling has its own logic: *a lot of bananas* is a typical noun phrase whereas *alot of bananas* would be pretty odd; *the lot of them* and *the whole lot* are occasionally heard; and so on. But you can see how someone might make the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simply a misspelling. In the case of "a lot", it's a term that's frequently used, and it might seem like one word when pronounced. So I'm thinking that until told differently, kids think that "a lot" is one word.

Comment: That may be all it is. It just seems so incredibly prevalent. And the same does not occur with most similar pairs of words For example, I've never seen anyone write "lotsof" or "hasto".

Comment: haha, true that. But look at those words you just made up. They look less "right" than "alot". No, I don't know why people do this...

Comment: "a lot" sounds like one word in contradistinction to "lotsof"

Answer (score 1):

I can't post images in comments, but I think this one is worth a tenth of a myriad’s words:

[image: ngram]

So: no, it's not “on its way to becoming a recognised single word”.

<sup>And most of the hits from this ngram are not actual uses of “alot” in the context we are discussing here, but OCR issues or names of foreign places.</sup>

Comment: what is the source of this graph? Care to share?

Comment: @teylyn: it's a Google ngram, and I edited the post so that the image links to the original graph. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime, I had already found the Google ngram site by googling "ngram". Neat site!!

Comment: That's a good graph alright.

Comment: @F'x: You argue that alot is “on its way to becoming a recognised single word” but this graph only proves that "alot" is much less common than "a lot". [There are plenty of recognized words which are comparably rare as "alot"](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=alot%2Cxanthan&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). And I can make [a graph that "proves" than even "a lot" is not recognized as a term by the same metric](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=a+lot%2Cthe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: I think your graph is heavily skewed because Google ngrams looks at books, maybe journals & newspapers, and as far as I know, doesn't include things like text messages, facebook statuses or small comments like this one, where the "alot" spelling is much more likely to occur.